# EasyMock for injecting mocks and mock private method f

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm writing Testcases using EasyMock. My use case is

1. I need to do injecting mocks and
2. mock private method(method of the class to be tested) call .

I searched internet and found injecting mocks can be done using `EasyMockRunner`. and private method call can be mocked using `PowerMockRunner`. And compiler is not allowing to add 2 runners on same testclass. I'm not able to find any other way to do these 2 things.

Any suggestions on other ways to achieve them are most welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Use only PowerMockRunner.

Comment: In UnitTest you verify the *public behavior* of the class under test. If you need to mock a *private method* on your code under test you most likely have a *design problem* which you should solve in the first place. PowerMock is almost ever a surrender to bad design.

Comment: I would like to strongly discourage you from trying to test private methods - as @TimothyTruckle said, writing hacks such as using PowerMock or using reflection is in most cases the result of bad design. The classes are black boxes and you should only verify the outputs, based on given inputs. One way around this is to declare them as package friendly and create the test class under the same package structure - this way the methods could be accessed from the test without exposing them publicly. The preferred way is to encapsulate the functionality into classes and test/mock those separately.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved injecting mocks using Whitebox.setInternalState(spiedMockObject,"attribute_tobeinjected",mockedValueToinject);

and sideways I could call private methods using PowerMock without any hassles.